# On-screen keyboard not working when USB barcode scanner is connected

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, android-usb

I'm developping a inventory management app, and want to use an kitkat tablet as the end-user device. I use an USB barcode reader which works fine.

My problem is that once the barcode reader is plugged in, it's recognized as a real keyboard, and I can't access the virtual keyboard anymore. This is a big issue for me, because I only use the barcode reader to read barcodes, and need the soft keyboard beside...

But When i use marshmallow that's time barcode reader and virtual keyboard works fine. but kitkat and lollipop not working as well.

Is there any way to enable both virtual and real keyboards ? I really need help on this....

Thank you !

Comment: I too having the same problem.. please post answer if any one knows the solution.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think what you're asking for was available until Android 5.0 unfortunately. If you're aiming for later versions of Android, you should be able to enable both in the settings menu.

*Android 5.0*

Languages and Input > Current keyboard > Turn "Hardware Show Input Methods" ON

*Android 8.0*

System > Languages and Input > Physical Keyboard > Turn "Show virtual keyboard" ON