# How to enable both hardware and Software keyboards on Flutter App

Tags: flutter, mobile

i have a flutter app with a barcode scanner. Since the scanner is an hardware keyboard the app doesn't show me the software keyboard. Unless i set it visible in the device settings

How can i force the Software keyboard to be Open and Usable?

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8143805/how-to-disable-physical-keyboard-in-codeuse-virtual-keyboard-all-the-time

Comment: similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410807/on-screen-keyboard-not-working-when-usb-barcode-scanner-is-connected?rq=3